# With sequelize within express js how to return multiple records from the association table

Tags: sequelize.js

I am looking for assistance with Sequelize on how to query a many to many relationship but also return the multiple record from the association table

What I have is a user table associated to a session table via usersession table.
usersession table has a PK and the FK are not unique. but when I run a sequelize.findall, the results do not include the multiple rows in the association table.

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize, User, Session) => {
  const UserSessions = sequelize.define("usersession", {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    }, 
    sessionDate: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
});


User.belongsToMany(Session, {through: { model: UserSessions, unique: false }});
Session.belongsToMany(User, {through: { model: UserSessions, unique: false }});

return UserSessions;
```

};

When I run the SQL I do get the multiple rows but the returned data only has the data for one associated row.

[Returned SQL query data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrUxF.png)

[Returned data from sequelize query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzDrd.png)

This is how I am querying using sequelize

```
Users.findAll({ where: { 'id': req.query.userId }, include: Sessions, require: true })
.then(data => {
    console.log(data);
})
```

Any ideas on how to be able to return the multiple association rows without having to make another query?

Answer (score 0):

you must not be returning an array from the resolver or function where you call the findAll but you would need to post more code to know for sure

Answer (score 0):

Thank but I subsequently found that in sequelize you can run your own sql query and that is returning the values I am requiring.

```
var sql="SELECT `sessions`.`name` AS `name`, `sessions`.`day` AS `day`, `sessions`.`starttime` AS `starttime`, `sessions`.`duration` AS `duration`, `sessions->usersession`.`id` AS `id`, `sessions->usersession`.`sessionDate` AS `sessionDate` FROM `users` AS `user` LEFT OUTER JOIN ( `usersessions` AS `sessions->usersession` INNER JOIN `sessions` AS `sessions` ON `sessions`.`id` = `sessions->usersession`.`sessionId`) ON `user`.`id` = `sessions->usersession`.`userId` WHERE `user`.`id` = '" + req.query.userId + "'";
```